# CSS background image wont stay put

Tags: css, background, position

My problem is this: I am using three background images for my web page, two of them I am able to position correctly using the 'background-position' property however the third image (lady.png) will not stay where I want it on the page when the browser window is stretched wider. It appears that she is being positioned relative the the edge of the browser. I have tried to use the 'background-attachment:fixed' to keep the photo in one place but that is not working.

What I want is for the main top and bottom graphics to be aligned 'top center' and for the image of the woman to be about 200px from the left and 300px down from the top. I have already tried 'background-position: 200px 300px' but she still moves with the frame. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code as of now for this page: http://dev.salonbuilder.com/website/150099/services.asp

```
<td width="100%" style="background-image:url(<%=ImagePath%>lady.png),url(<%=ImagePath%>new-bg-top.jpg),url(<%=ImagePath%>new-bg-line.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat-y;background-position:80px 150px, top center,top center; background-attachment: fixed, relative, relative;">
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can format a little more your code

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... how can I format the code more?

Comment: You need to indent your code by 4 spaces so it be formated and you are missing "<" in the beginning of td tag

Comment: I removed the starting caret because the stackoverflow text box was not showing the complete code with the < showing. It is not missing in the site code. How would indenting the code make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. Since you aren't using responsive design, you can assign a fixed width to your `<table>` tag and that would solve the problem of the lady.png image moving to the left when you zoom out of the website. You can add the following style to the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
table {
     width: 1349px;
}
```

or add it inline like this:

```
<table width="1349px" height="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">...</table>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, I actually had the table width set originally but the problem there is that the site is no longer centered in the frame. If the browser window is not 1349px wide then the main content section is offset by about 200px and that is not ideal. I am trying to find a way to use CSS to center the other background images and make the lady.png stationary. Any other thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another solution which came in my mind is that you can set the `background-position` to `top center, top center, top center` and then edit the lady.png image using a photo editing software in such a manner that it has the right amount of transparent space from the top and the left so that it appears at the right position on the website.